# How to integrate previous predictions in Keras custom loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss

I want to create a custom loss function is Keras, where the loss of the current prediction `y_pred` depends for the prediction of the previous training sample `XXX` and other parameters `h, b, K`. The loss function looks like the following and I don't know how to call the previous prediction (i.e. replace `XXX`) in Keras **during training**.

(for context: it's a loss function for quantile regression + fixed costs)

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, h, b, K, XXX):
    if y_pred > XXX:
        F = K
    else:
        F = 0
    loss = h * max(0, y_pred - y_true) + b * max(0, y_true - y_pred) + F
    return loss
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the goal with this? You would create a dependency on the order of your data set, and I don't see how this would work in batch mode, or using any kind of SGD. How do you handle edge cases like the first training sample?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738435/how-to-make-a-custom-loss-function-that-uses-previous-output-from-network-in-ker) help

Comment: There will be absolutely no effect in backpropagation.

Comment: The goal is to solve an inventory optimization problem. Yes, it is dependent on the order of the data as I'm working with time series data. If SGD works is indeed not clear.
What do you mean by "no effect in backpropagation"?